# How to "inherit" a method when the class already has a parent class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

```
public class StudentDm : EntityBaseDm {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FormattedName
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
        }
    }
}

public class ProviderDm {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FormattedName
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a Student class that inherits EntityBaseDm.
I have a Provider class that I do not want inheriting EntityBaseDm.

I want to extract the FormattedName get method and implementation into a generic class however I don't want to put it in EntityBaseDm since it is general. I will have to make an Interface such as IFirstLastName but an interface doesn't let me implement functions. I know there are many design patterns out there, one of which can solve this problems. I wonder if anyone can point me to the right direction (at least the right pattern to use)

Comment: FormattedName is a property, not a function/method

Comment: yes, but the return LastName + ", " + FirstName is a method implementation. It will be much complex than that but for example i simpliefied it down. There will be 10 classes that will use this function and I  want to find a way to extract it out without making it generic for all Dm classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @ScottHannen's advice on this. Object composition would be a good fit.

However, you could create that `IFirstLastName` interface you mentioned, then create an extension method.

```
public interface IFirstLastName
{
    string FirstName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
}

public static class IFirstLastNameExtensions
{
    public static string FormattedName(this IFirstLastName fln)
    {
        return $"{fln.LastName}, {fln.FirstName}";
    }
}

public class StudentDm : EntityBaseDm, IFirstLastName
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ProviderDm : IFirstLastName
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could call the `FormattedName` method on any class which implements `IFirstLastName`:

```
var dm = new ProviderDm();
dm.FormattedName();
```

Comment: Thanks alot!!.. while Scott's answer is very good.. this one suits my need the most since it allows for more flexibility. For example, I might have different annotations (ex. [Required] or [MaxLength]) for FirstName in the various classes. And composition will not allow me to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Before going any further, consider what will happen if you create yet another method that some of these objects should share, but others shouldn't. Trying to bring together functions through inheritance can suddenly get messy. It doesn't work more often than it does.

You may have heard the recommendation to "favor composition over inheritance." In broad terms it means that it's better to bring things together that provide needed functions rather than try achieve a hierarchy where the functions you need are in base classes.

If a "name" needs consistent functionality like formatting, that's a case for making it its own class.

```
public class Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FormattedName { get { return LastName + ", " + FirstName; } }
}
```

Then have a property on `StudentDm`

```
public Name StudentName { get; set;}
```

However you do it, I wouldn't recommend placing classes in a hierarchy just because of a few shared properties. Sooner or later (usually sooner) something comes along that belongs in some of the inherited classes but not others and then it gets complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is an [abstract class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/sf985hc5.aspx). This is similar to an interface in that you can define declarations for the implementing classes, but you can also define implementations in the abstract class itself.

For example, you could have an abstract `NameBase` class like so:

```
public abstract NameBase : EntityBaseDm
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FormattedName
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
        }
    }
}
```

Your implementing classes then inherit the abstract class:

```
public class StudentDm : NameBase {
}

public class ProviderDm : NameBase {
}
```

Note, you do not need to define the name properties in either of these classes, but they are still available to use:

```
var student = new StudentDm();
student.FirstName = "John";
student.LastName = "Smith";

var fullName = student.FormattedName; // returns Smith, John
```

Comment: It should be noted that he *may* or *may not* want an abstract class. Its quite possible he would want to use/instantiate the `NameBase` for something and an abstract class would not allow for that.

Comment: @Mikanikal there's nothing in his question to suggest that, and an abstract class fulfills his requirements. Also note that the method could be marked `virtual` allowing it to be overwritten in the implementing class.

Comment: there is nothing in his post to suggest the opposite. That is why I said *may* or *may not*. Just trying to point out that "The answer is an Abstract Class" is not the **only** answer and he should understand all his options.

Comment: Sorry, i think i didnt make my question clear. I updated it. The purpose is that this can be used by any class that has a FirstName and LastName. Therefore a class that has a FirstName and LastName that does not inherit the EntityBaseDm should also be able to use this. I am not sure if this is possible but I want to at least be able to explore my options.

Comment: This answer doesn't entirely work, as now `ProviderDm` is a child class of `EntityBaseDm` - something it wasn't in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for multiple inheritance and that is not possible with c#. Your option is to create an intermediate class that inherits from `EntityBaseDM` and only implements the method you want. Your `ProviderDm` or `StudentDm` would derive from `IntermediateBaseDM` and provide more properties.

```
class IntermediateBaseDM : EntityBaseDM
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FormattedName
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + ", " + FirstName;
        }
    }
}
```